Can numerical differentiation be applied to tensor derivatives?
This isn't fully programming-related but I do need to implement this in a Fortran code so I am hoping that someone can help me here.
I know that for a 1D function, I can calculate the numerical derivative at every point, (x1,y1), with dy/dx where dy = y2 - y0 and dx = x2 - x0. If my step size is small enough, the slope can be approximated as linear.
I know that the derivative of a tensor, A, with dimensions nxn, with another tensor, B, with dimensions nxn, will yield a 4th rank tensor of dimension nxnxnxn.
The question is on extending the linear approximation to tensor:
If I just want a rough estimate of the derivative of A with respect to B, dA/dB, is it ok to calculate the components of dA/dB following the numerical differentiation formula above? i.e. for n = 6, I have:
dA/dB(1,1,1,1) = (A2(1,1) - A1(1,1)) / (B2(1,1) - B1(1,1))

dA/dB(1,2,1,1) = (A2(1,2) - A1(1,2)) / (B2(1,1) - B1(1,1))

dA/dB(1,3,1,1) = (A2(1,3) - A1(1,3)) / (B2(1,1) - B1(1,1))

... and so on, where A1 and A2 are the tensors A at two consecutive time steps.
Thanks in advance!
